# Count amount of similar items in array, return value if under 3

Tags: php, arrays, count, duplicates

I have an array which contains sets of three similar named items; however, sometimes there's only two items in a set and I want to call these out.

```
<?php
$items = array(
'reviewpitfighter-1.138x88.jpg',
'reviewpitfighter-2.138x88.jpg',
'reviewpopfulmailsegacd-1.138x92.jpg',
'reviewpopfulmailsegacd-2.138x76.jpg',
'reviewpopfulmailsegacd-3.138x97.jpg'
);
?>
```

You'll note that there are two reviewpitfigher* items, and three reviewpopfulmailsegacd* items. I've started down a rabbit hole of loops and feel that there is something simple I'm just glossing over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with, sorry it took so long to post.

```
foreach($images as $value){
    $lastItem = explode('-', $images[$count - 1]);
    $parts = explode('-', $value);
    if(preg_match('/^1/', $parts[1]) && $count != 0){
        if(preg_match('/^2/',$lastItem[1])){
            $imgurl = preg_replace('/^p?review/','',$lastItem[0]);
            $sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE field = "' . $imgurl . '"';
            $result = $dbConn->FetchArray($dbConn->Query($sql), MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $array[$imgurl] = $result;
        }
    }
    $count++;
}
```

I get an array of all the images, then I check to see if I'm looking at the first image, if I am then I see if the last image I looked at was the second image. At this point I then call into the database to get some information to display a neatly messaged out put of what reviews are missing a third image. In the end `$array` contains this list which I can loop over.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do this as a 2 stage process.

Stage 1:

Loop through the original array and form another set of array with its key as the value of this original array. Then save the repetition count in each of those new arrays.

Stage 2:

Loop through the new set of arrays and then pick out the arrays which has values less than 3 and retrieve its key.

Hope this helps!!